# Python local name in nest function

Tags: python

I had a test for local variable in nest function,
I got the error as the following code:

```
# coding: utf-8

def func3():
    x = [1, 2, 3]

    def func2():
        print 'func2:', locals()
        x[0] += x[0]
        print 'func2:', locals()

    def func3():
        print 'func3:', locals()
        x = x[0]
        print 'func3:', locals()

    func2()
    print "-->", locals()

    func3()
    print "==>", locals()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func3()
```

I got the error:

```
func2: {'x': [1, 2, 3]}

func2: {'x': [2, 2, 3]}

--> {'func3': <function func3 at 0x1076adde8>, 'func2': <function func2 at 0x1076ad6e0>, 'x': [2, 2, 3]}

func3: {}

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>

    func3()

  File "test.py", line 19, in func3

    func3()
  File "test.py", line 13, in func3

    x = x[0]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Why did `func2` and `func3` have the different answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an assignment to a variable in a function, a local variable is created in that function and all references to the same name are assumed to be to that local variable. Otherwise, the references to a variable are assumed to go to an outer scope.

In `func2` there is no assignment to `x` (there is an assignment to `x[0]`, but that's not the same thing). Therefore it refers to the outer `x` and everything works correctly.

However, in `func3` there is an assignment to `x`. Therefore `x` in that function refers to a new variable local to that function, and `x = x[0]` is wrong because it tries to read from an uninitialized variable.

In Python 3, you can put `nonlocal x` in `func3` to assign to the outer `x` instead. In Python 2, there is no simple way to assign to a variable from an outer non-global scope. The usual workaround is to use indexing like in `func2` or write to an attribute (`x.attr = val`).

Answer (score 0):

In `func3()`, you are trying to modify the variable in the outer scope.  You didn't say that it isn't local, however, so Python says the local variable is referenced before assignment.  To modify the outer variable, you need to declare it nonlocal (in Python3):

```
def func3():
    nonlocal x
    print 'func3:', locals()
    x = x[0]
    print 'func3:', locals()
```

That won't work in Python2, however, because `nonlocal` does not exist.  One workaround would be to declare `x` global both in the outer `func3()` and the inner `func3()`.

In the case of `func2()`, you don't actually need that because `x[0] += x[0]` is really a shortcut for `x[0].__iadd__(x[0])`.  Since you are allowed to *reference* `x`, that does what you want.

Comment: `x` is not global, it's from an outer scope. And `func2` is correct without any addition `global` or `nonlocal` declaration.

Comment: @interjay I have already edited my answer, but you came 27 seconds too early.  See my comment on the other answer for my comeback on `global` and `nonlocal`.

Comment: The answer is still wrong. `func2` does access the outer variable.

Comment: @interjay: For once, I admit it.  I ran the code, and I discovered that you were right.  It then occurred to me why.  See my edited answer.